# Laravel replace variable on Model

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I would like to be able to override a variable on the model, so that a normal field is instead replaced by a relationship's field, i.e.

Where `product.image` might normally be a field, I want to run a function which will go through all of the resulting products from a query and replace the `image` field with something like the following --

`(Product.php) Model`

```
...

public function variantImages(){
    return $this->image = $this->variants()->first()->pluck('image_url');
}

...
```

So the default product image field is replaced by the "first product variant's image". I don't want to do this in a collection once I have already got the data, the problem here is being able to do this at a Model level.

Is there a way to do this within a scope?

Answer (score 1):

You can [create an accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) instead of a normal function:

```
// Singular because it only gets one
public function getVariantImageAttribute(){
    return $this->image = $this->variants()->first()->pluck('image_url');
}
```

This will make it available under `$product->variant_image`

Then you can ensure it is always appended to your model (if you want) by adding it to the appends e.g.:

```
$appends = [ 'variant_image' ];
```

Since this is not the best idea since it will force load the relationship every time you get a product (even if you didn't request it) you can conditionally control when to append it via e.g.:

```
return response()->json($product->append('variant_image'));
```

Note that the `append` method also works for [collecitions of eloquent models](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-collections#method-append).